# Certain validator nodes produce more blocks than other nodes (BABE)

Tags: validator, babe, block-production

At Ternoa we are observing an interesting phenomenon where a node operator consistently produces more blocks than other node operators. In this case, he has two validator nodes and both nodes produce more block than any other validator.

Our chain uses BABE for block production. The C is set to [1, 4]; allowedSlots is set to PrimaryAndSecondaryPlainSlots; all the Babe Authorities have 1 as BabeAuthorityWeight; We have currently 15 active validator slots.

Any insights on why this phenomenon is manifesting? One idea that I have is that those nodes are more often chosen when a fork happens but I don't know how true that is.

Comment: Are you monitoring networking? Perhaps poor connectivity is a cause.

Comment: @DanShields I am looking at the telemetry data and I see nothing out of order for those nodes. The block time and block propagation time are fine, only the peer amount is quite low ( <25) compared to other nodes (other nodes have >25 peers).

Comment: @DanShields Also how can poor connectivity cause a node to produce more blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this have been fixed without doing anything from our side.